# Exchange 2007 issue: PDF attachments with name longer than 20 characters won't go through

Tags: exchange

Odd issue here I've been intermittently dealing with for months now. Certain PDF's sent as email attachments inbound cannot go through. I have confirmed the issue is with the PDF **attachment filename *length***. Other PDF's with shorter names go through just fine. From my testing, the max length the PDF can have is about 20 characters, even though I read that Exchange '07 should be able to process up to 78, at a minimum.

Also noteworthy is the fact that if the test PDF with a long name (about 60 characters) is sent *internally* on our domain, there are no problems and it goes through fine.

I've been searching online for hours now and I cannot find Exch Mgmt Shell commands or Exch Mgmt Console (GUI) instructions to even check the attachement character limits, much less change them. Any/all help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a symantec product on the server?

Comment: I am not now, but I believe my predecessor was so it might still be in effect! Checking....

Comment: ...I found and deleted a leftover "Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager" folder from Program Files, but cannot find a running Symantec service at all. We use ESET now.

Comment: Note: I meant this as a question, not an answer but don't have enough points yet. What do you get if you run get-transportagent ? You could setup a pipeline trace to see if any of the agents change the attachment: Get-transportserver | set-transportserver -pipelinetracingenabled $true -pipelinetracingsenderaddress user@mail.com -pipelinetracingpath c:\PipelineTrace

Comment: Thank you! This is what I received from the 'get-transportagent' command in Exch Mgmt Shell:
http://pastebin.com/wf4U1Cqf

Comment: Cannot make the PS command work:
[PS] C:\>Get-transportserver | set-transportserver -piplinetracingenabled $true
Set-TransportServer : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '
piplinetracingenabled'.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my comment, should be: Get-transportserver | set-transportserver -pipelinetracingenabled $true -pipelinetracingsenderaddress user@mail.com -pipelinetracingpath c:\PipelineTrace

Comment: The transport agents don't show any 3rd party agents but it's still worth checking with a pipeline trace.

Comment: Thank you, smwk. I ran the command and it first returned something about using Set-TransportServer (to set permissions), but I erased it too quickly. Then I reran the command and it just said:
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of ('MailServer_name') have been modified.

Comment: Could our old AV (Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager) have modified the TransportServer settings?? It has since been uninstalled, but a previous poster said that could by my issue here.

Comment: That's fine the trace should be setup now, it's just a warning that it shouldn't be left on. There is no Symantec agent present so it is unlikely to be an issue. What service pack and rollup are installed for Exchange? Just one server?

Comment: Version: 08.03.0389.002, so Update Rollup 15 for Exchange Server 2007 SP3

Comment: ...and yes, just the one server. Will try updating to latest Rollup, 19.

Comment: Well, the damn Exchange Rollup broke other stuff and still didn't fix my $#*%&$ issue! Rolling it back tonight!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In testing I found that Exchange 2007 would truncate file names to 155-160 characters on mails sent internally. I guess if the mail comes from an external source then the pipeline trace won't help but you could enable SMTP logging to see what happens with the external mail server. Does the whole mail not get delivered or just the attachment?

Comment: Entire email is not delivered. I tried updating to the latest rollup (19), so will try again..

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2007 SP3 **Rollup 19** fixed the issue!